# Vim treatment vimrc if folder

Tags: vim

I'm currently working on my .vimrc, and theres is something i don't know about.

I made this line :

```
"=====[ On vim load, toggle NERDTree and switch to file ]=====        
autocmd VimEnter * :NERDTreeToggle | wincmd l
```

Which open nerdtree on load when i open vim, then switch to the main buffer after.

This work nice, but i want this cmd only when I open a folder :

```
vim .
```

But when I'm working on file only I don't need it.

```
vim mytext.md
```

I'm looking for a condition on my rc file, but I don't find it. Something like :

```
"=====[ On vim load, toggle NERDTree and switch to file ]=====        
if typefile != 'file'

autocmd VimEnter * :NERDTreeToggle | wincmd l

endif
```

So if you have an idea on this...

thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
augroup vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) | NERDTreeToggle | wincmd l | endif
augroup END
```

But I'm sure there's already a definitive solution somewhere on the internet.

See `:help argc()`, `:help argv()` and `:help isdirectory()`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work like a charm. I search before posting this, I try to improv myself in vim script but my eyes are not really accurate yet in this.